# HTML not calling Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am having difficulty figuring out what is wrong with these files.  Firebug loads the HTML and the .js files but when you push the button on the HTML file it does not do anything.  Putting breakpoints in firebug shows that the .js code is not talking to the HTML file.  I do not know if Javascript is not working because of something else in the code or I have a really silly mistake in the HTML file.  Thanks for any help.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Dice Roller</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "main.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="roller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="roller_library.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

<h1>Dice Roller</h1><br/><br/>
Die 1: <span id="die_1">&nbsp;</span><br /><br />
Die 2: <span id="die_2">&nbsp;</span><br /><br />
<label>Message: </label>
<span id="message">&nbsp;</span><br/><br />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="roll" value="Roll the Dice" /> <br/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

roller.js

```
var die = new Die();
var pairofDice = PairofDice();

var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

var update_display = function() {
var specialMsg;
var die_1 = ParseInt(Die.getValue1());
var die_2 = ParseInt(Die.getValue2());
 $("die_1").value = die_1;
 $("die_2").value = die_2;

var sum = PairofDice.getSum(die_1, die_2);
switch (sum){
    case "2":
        specialMsg = "Snake eyes"
        break;
    case "7":
        specialMsg = "Craps";
        break;
    case "12":
        specialMsg = "Box Cars";
        break;
    }

 $("message").value = specialMsg;
}

var rollDice_click = function() {
 $("die_1").value = "";
 $("die_2").value = "";

 update_display();
}

window.onload = function() {
$("roll").onclick = rollDice_click;
}
```

roller_library.js

```
var Die = function(sides) {
this.sides = 6;
return this;
}
Die.prototype.roll = function(sides) {
this.sides = sides;
do{
    number = parseInt (10 * Math.random());
} while (number >this.sides || number <1);

return number;
}
Die.prototype.getValue = function() {
this.roll = Die.roll();
return this;
}

var PairofDice = function(sides) {
this.sides = 6;
return this;
}
PairofDice.prototype.roll = function() {
Die.roll(6);
return number;
}
PairofDice.prototype.getValue1 = function() {
Die.getValue();
return;
}
PairofDice.prototype.getValue2 = function() {
Die.getValue();
return;
}
PairofDice.prototype.getSum = function(d1,d2) {
var sum;

var die1 = parseInt(d1);
var die2 = parseInt(d2);

sum = die1 + die2;

return sum;
}
```

The other option is that I am not understanding what I should be doing, if that is the case please let me know so I can get more one on one help.

Comment: `$("roll")` should be `$("#roll")` - and where are you referencing the js files?

Comment: @Shannon `$` is defined in the code, its not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I entirely jumped the gun on the onclick issue, so I took a more indepth look at the code. Theres a couple of  problems, the code won't even run nevermind the onclick not working. So, I fixed it and added some comments that might help you figure our where you went wrong if you compare it to your code. This is by no means best practice code, I've just tried to translate your code idea into working code so hopefully you can learn from it.

Please let me know if it helps or you need anything clarified :)

```
// Can't do this at the start of the script as they are undefined
//var die = new Die();
//var pairofDice = PairofDice();

// This is a good idea
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

// Let's include the model code ahead of the application code
// Our Die, when rolled it should have update it's value
var Die = function(sides) {
    // Let's use the parameter to decide how many sides our die has
    // " || 6" means that if sides has no value, it will default to 6
    // This helps us prevent errors from having no number of sides
    // defined when we roll the dice
    this.sides = sides || 6;

    // We will be able to access the value from elsewhere, but let's give
    // it an initial random value!
    this.value = this.roll();

    return this;
}

// Extending our Die's prototype to allow rolling!
// We don't need the sides parameter anymore, compare this old version
Die.prototype.old_roll = function(sides) {
    // This would remove any value we have previously assigned to sides
    this.sides = sides;
    // This loop will create a bias in the random numbers generated and if
    // the number of sides is greater than 10, it will never show it
    do {
        number = parseInt(10 * Math.random());
    } while (number > this.sides || number < 1);

    return number;
}

// Cleaner version of roll
Die.prototype.roll = function() {
    // Get a random number [ This will be a decimal number between 0 and 1]
    var random_number = Math.random()
    // Multiply it by (#no of sides - 1) 
    // [This will be a decimal value between 0 and the (#no of sides - 1)]
    var scaled_number = (this.sides - 1) * random_number
    // We round the number so it's always an integer number
    // We also add one to the result so we get a number between (1..# of sides)
    // It should be clear that we had to subtract from the number of sides before
    // we multiplied so that whenever we add one here we don't go outside our 
    // desired range of numbers (else the dice would read 1..7 with only 6 sides
    var result = Math.round(scaled_number) + 1

    // Assign the result to our die for future reference
    this.value = result

    // Return the result
    return result
}

/* We have no need for getValue as we can access the value of the dice
Die.prototype.getValue = function() {
    this.roll = Die.roll();
    return this;
}*/

// The PairofDice should help us manage 2 dice   
var PairofDice = function(sides) {
    // The sides parameter will help us initialise the two dice
    this.dice1 = new Die(sides);
    this.dice2 = new Die(sides);

    return this;
}

// When we roll the pair, it should roll each dice individually
// It will return an array with the value of each roll, for convenience
PairofDice.prototype.roll = function() {
    var roll1 = this.dice1.roll();
    var roll2 = this.dice2.roll();
    return [roll1, roll2];
}

// Return the value of the first dice
PairofDice.prototype.getValue1 = function() {
    return this.dice1.value;
}

// Likewise for the second dice
PairofDice.prototype.getValue2 = function() {
    return this.dice2.value;
}

// Return the total score for all dices, there is no need to take
// any parameters to this function as we have all the data within 
// our PairOfDice instace (referenced by 'this' keyword)
PairofDice.prototype.getSum = function() {
    // No need to parseInt on these values as we only store integer values
    var sum = this.dice1.value + this.dice2.value;

    return sum;
}


// Now we can define our variables 
// There is no need to make an instance of Die as we can just use
// PairofDice to manage 2 dice for us, make sure to use the new keyword!
//var die = new Die();
var pairofDice = new PairofDice();    

// Updating the display when a roll is made
var update_display = function() {
    var specialMsg;

    // We can simplify this a lot now
    //var die_1 = ParseInt(Die.getValue1());
    //var die_2 = ParseInt(Die.getValue2());

    // value doesn't set the text on span, so we will use innerText
    $("die_1").innerText = pairofDice.getValue1();
    $("die_2").innerText = pairofDice.getValue2();

    // Get the sum of the roll
    //var sum = PairofDice.getSum(die_1, die_2);
    var sum = pairofDice.getSum();

    // In the switch statement, it should be integer cases instead of string
    switch (sum) {
    case 2:
        specialMsg = "Snake eyes"
        break;
    case 7:
        specialMsg = "Craps";
        break;
    case 12:
        specialMsg = "Box Cars";
        break;
     // we add a default message incase there is no special, because then it will print 'undefined'
    default:
        specialMsg = "No luck";
    }

    // Show the message!
    $("message").innerText = specialMsg;
}

var rollDice_click = function() {
    // These aren't needed as the value will always be updated
    //$("die_1").value = "";
    //$("die_2").value = "";

    // Roll the dice..
    pairofDice.roll();
    // Show the results!
    update_display();
}

window.onload = function() {
    $("roll").onclick = rollDice_click;
}​
```

Comment: Incorrect. [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) is not provided by jQuery. Given a DOM element, `onclick = function() { }` is a completely valid way of specifying a click handler.

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun :P

Answer (score 0):

roller.js is being run before roller_library.js is even loaded so neither Die nor PairOfDice are defined when Die is used on line 1 of roller.js. So the roller.js JavaScript aborts with a failure at that point and the window.onload line is never executed.

Comment: Yeah, this is an important issue that I was pointing out in my answer before I just decided to rewrite it all as the code was riddled with bugs even without that headache :(